# React onMouseOver not working with any functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

(I am new to React) This might be something simple but I have looked through a number of other issues like this and cant figure out what I am doing wrong. I am trying to just do a simple function on `onMouseOver` but for some reason it is never called.

Here is what I have thus far:

```js
export default class CardLineItemProgressBarPart extends React.Component<Props> {
  constructor(props:Props) {
    super(props)
    this.showPopup = this.showPopup.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  
  }

  xOffset = 0;
  yOffset = 0;
  visible = false;

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="CardLineItemProgressBarPart"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: this.props.color,
        width: (this.props.percent + '%')
      }}
      onMouseOver={() => console.log("mouse enter")}>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But I never see anything logged in the console. Am I missing something simple? This worked for me for `onClick` on another Component so I tried to mimic that here which I think I did but neither work on this component.

Comment: Can you set width and height in pixels may be it does not see the element.
for example width: 50px; height: 50px;

Comment: I can see the element in the web browser myself so it is rendering the object. And just for sanity sake I did try that, it didnt do anything unfortunately

Comment: do other handlers work for this element, for example onClick, onMouseEnter?

what version of react do you use?

I would rewrite it with a functional approach and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing that I had adjusted z-index for some CSS layout and it put the element behind another.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div 
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        width: '400px',
        height: '400px'
      }}
      onMouseOver={() => console.log("mouse enter")}>
    </div>`
```

This works, so something else must be wrong.

See sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-mendel-wpfn55?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yeah it works in other places too but I am having trouble figuring out where the issue lies in this one.